# Opencart: Error for certain email ids with domain extensions other than .com

Tags: php, opencart

Tried my bit, but not successful.

I have setup my opencart and everything is working pretty fine.

There is a small issue, when any user tries to register with WRONG email id having domain extension (WHICH DOES NOT EXIST) (I WAS TRYING THIS FOR TESTING PURPOSES), opencart do not respond and i got below error in my error log opencart.

```
PHP Notice:  Error: RCPT TO not accepted from server! in public_html/system/library/mail.php on line 307
```

Than i saw an blank page when i click on Create account.

Similar is the case if user add a product to cart and then register a account WITH EMAIL HAVING INVALID DOMAIN NAME. Webpage just hangs out there...processing...processing...processing...

There is no Exception catch/code handling this issue error. Thus page hangs and sometimes blank page with above error. As i am using SMTP.

Comment: Are you using smtp or default mail?

Comment: There is nothing You can do from within the OpenCart nor Your webhosting. This is some weird restriction Your webhosting provider has set on his email server. Contact their support and ask for explanation or for exception for Your hosting (make sure to mention that without this Your business cannot continue and without making this work You will need to change the provider - this usually helps very often).

Comment: @SankarV : as of now i am using SMTP and emails are working 100/100. Now if i changed it to MAIL, email stops working but i am unable to register with .org and .net..:-(..

Comment: @shadyyx: i confirmed from my josting. They said, there is no restriction from our side. Can you please advise any other possible issue

Comment: @shadyyx : I tested it more and more..I found that, above error occurs for the domain which does not exist, it is not for any .org, .net etc..Like its working for valid email@domain.net where domain.net exists. But for invalid domain, there is no exception catcher..Shadyyx: could you help in this...Also i have edited the question for more clarification

Comment: @SankarV : I have updated the question as i tested more deeply into it after hosting provider confirmation...could you please advise something now